# In xcode, how to call a class method which returns a value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to Objective-C and for the life of me cannot get past the error, "no class method for selector"

Here is my .h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhotoCapViewController : UIViewController < UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate > {
    UIImageView * imageView;
    UIButton * choosePhotoBtn;
    UIButton * takePhotoBtn;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * choosePhotoBtn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton * takePhotoBtn;
- (IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender;

+ (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img;

@end
```

Here is the function I have defined in .m

```
+ (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img {

    ...

    return theImage;
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the function

```
UIImage* image1 = [PhotoCapViewController burnTextIntoImagetext:text1 img:imageView.image];
```

Any help would would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method you are calling doesn't match the definition.

The definition is this:

```
+ (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img;
```

so the method name is this:

```
burnTextIntoImage::
```

But you call it like this:

```
UIImage* image1 = [PhotoCapViewController burnTextIntoImagetext:text1 img:imageView.image];
```

so you're trying to call a method named this:

```
burnTextIntoImagetext::
```

You could call it correctly like this:

```
UIImage* image1 = [PhotoCapViewController burnTextIntoImage:text1 :imageView.image];
```

Though really, your method should be called `burnText:(NSString*)text intoImage:(UIImage*)image`, so it makes more of a "sentence", like this:

```
+ (UIImage *)burnText:(NSString *)text intoImage:(UIImage *)image;

...

UIImage *image1 = [PhotoCapViewController burnText:text1 intoImage:imageView.image];
```

Comment: Your last paragraph is the _truly_ correct answer. The rest is just patching the immediate problem.

Comment: Agreed. By the way, if you ever change your favourite knot, please settle on a single SO username, or I'll totally lose track.

Comment: Noted. :) I've been "Josh Caswell" for the majority of my time here, though (which, by an astonishing coincidence, is also the name I use in real life).

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. This is my second day with Objective-C. I'm finding the syntax extremely challenging. I used to be a C# developer.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your method declaration is incomplete.

Change

```
+ (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img;
```

to

```
+ (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text img:(UIImage *)img;
```

Comment: Nice spot, I was focused on the calling code not matching, and missed the missing parameter name!

Comment: That's not a parameter name, it's part of the method name. The parameter name is to the right of the type.

Comment: That was it. It worked. I just tested it. Thanks!! I went with jrturton's solution as it is more like what I'm used to from C#. However, I have now learnt both ways of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Your calling code is wrong, try to use this code

```
UIImage* image = [PhotoCapViewController burnTextIntoImage:text1 img:imageView.image];
```

Comment: @CReaTuS : thanks but in the above declaration it has been done without _img_
**+ (UIImage *)burnTextIntoImage:(NSString *)text :(UIImage *)img;**